# Extremely slow response in XQuartz from remote linux server to my OS X Mojave XQuartz server

Tags: macos, ssh-tunnel, xquartz

I'm running XQuartz on my imac and using ssh -Y hostname to connect to a remote linux (debian 8) server.  The DISPLAY gets set appropriately and I can launch remote clients, but it takes 70 seconds to display a window locally when I type "xterm" at the prompt.  Obviously this is unacceptable performance.

When I launch Xemacs, it takes much longer before I can start typing and the widgets are just impossibly slow to draw and respond. (Yes, I know about vi :-P)

What causes this long delay and how can I eliminate it?